# Solution for specific database constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, unique-constraint

I need, in the DB, to have:

```
Id  C1  C2  C3    
1   T   R   P1    
2   T   R   P2    
3   T1  R   P1    
4   T1  R   P2    
5   T2  U   P1    
6   T2  U   P2
```

Given the data above, the DB is not allowed to have:

```
7   T1  U   P1    
8   T1  U   P2
```

That means:

If there is an occurence of value T1 in C1 with R in C2,
 
then no other rows containing T1 with other value than R must happen.

OR, another explanation:

Let x be column C1 = value 1, y column C2 = value 2. if (x,y) in DB with given values are present, then no other value 1 must happen with other y value than 2, but value 2 can happen with other value than 1

OR, new values example:

```
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 2 1
2 2 2
3 2 1
3 2 2
```

Valid.
Given this state of the DB, the below rows must not be possible to insert:

```
1 1 2
2 1 1
3 3 2
```

Basically this means that a 1 in first column can happen only with a 2 in column 2 given the original DB state.

Is it possible to achieve that kind of constraint? (Besides checking this in backend code, or trigger)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your constrain logic?? for example can this rows be valid `(T1,P, P1)` , `(T1,P, P3)` , `(T1,R, P1)` , `(T1,R, P3)`

Comment: Your example is the same as what I pointed above: (T1,R,P1), (T1, R, P2), (T1, U, P1), (T1, U, P2) as I see, and as such, no, it is not possible. C3 can have any value. C1, C2, C3 all have different data types.

Comment: yes, but im not sure of what is the constrain yet ... I think the logic is: `if exist (x,y,?) --> not exist (x,z,?)`  `where y= 'R'`

Comment: What about the reverse ... `if exist (x,z,?) and z <> 'R'` can i insert `(x,'R',?)` ?

Comment: Let x be column C1 = value 1, y column C2 = value 2. if (x,y) in DB with given values are present, then no other value 1 must happen with other y value than 2, but value 2 can happen with other value than 1. Sounds complicated, hope this will clear something.

Comment: You should try update your question with that info and use a better format so easy to understand. But I dont think you can do that with a restriction. Unless you keep one additional table as external FK

Comment: That's what I fear, sadly... Thx for help!

Comment: Again Im not sure what you want yet, so maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107991/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-xmight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constraint means that your schema is not properly normalized. You should remove the `C2` column from this table, and create another table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE C1_C2 (
    C1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
    C2 INT
);
```

Then your original table should have `C1` be a foreign key to `C1_C2.C1`, and you can use a `JOIN` to combine the two tables.

Comment: Yes, basically this is the solution, except that I still need a mechanism to enforce the idea that if C2 and C3 columns are in same table, and if C2 happens with a specific value from C1 column in the newly created table, then that specific value of C2 must not happen with other value from C1. But, anyway, you are right about normalization, and also you confirmed what I was thinking. Thank you!

Comment: That seems to be the opposite constraint from the one in your question.

Comment: If you use the table as in your original question, there's no way to enforce the constraint automatically. You could do it with a trigger that checks for violations before an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: Regarding the trigger, yes, you are right! Regarding the opposite thing, no, it's not. I would say that this would be another way to solve the problem. Thank you for inspiring me!

Comment: The question says that for each C1 value there can only be one C2 value. Your comment says that for each C2 value there can only be one C1 value. That seems to be the opposite.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Conceptually I was thinking about what you said, but wrote it using wrong column names, sorry.

Comment: Using real column names would probably make this all much more understanable and mistakes like this would be less likely.